# What is the best word to describe confusing two words?

Tags: synonyms

I am writing a speech and describing two words that are often confused for each other, "religion" and "faith". I have written this line:

> Faith and religion are often *mistaken* to mean the same thing.

I am trying to decide which is the best word to use (shown in italics): mistaken, misconstrued, confused? What is the best word to capture the idea of mistaking the definition?

Comment: Perhaps *misunderstood*?

Comment: I would say that no word in that category is appropriate, as the definitions of "faith" and "religion" overlap, and there are contexts where they can mean the same thing.

Comment: Does 'mistakenly thought' fit the bill? What IS the difference, I wonder?

Comment: As a matter of writing, I'd find the assertion that other people are "confusing" these terms for each other slightly arrogant. There are different distinctions that *may* be made between the words, but they can also be synonyms. Just use "considered" and then present the distinction you will be using in your speech.

Comment: I think you already said it, *"Faith and religion are often confused.*" I disagree when you say that it is the *words* that are often confused. It is actually the *concepts* that are confused and so the shorter sentence is more fitting.

Comment: I agree with @sumelic.  The *tone* of your line is quite 'lofty'.  You would  be less controversial if you started by saying that *Faith and religion are often **taken** to mean the same thing, however ...*.

Comment: This is why I posted the question, to find the best word or words to describe the concept. They do overlap, but they are not interchangeable terms. @chasly, could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**conflated**:

> Definition of CONFLATE
>
> *transitive verb*
>
> **1**
>
> - a :  to bring together* :  fuse
> - b :  confuse
>
> [source: Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflate)

*in this case, two disparate concepts, treating the signifying words as synonymous.

Comment: I think this might be the best grammatically, but I fear I would have to explain what conflate means next.